# Why is this throwing an internal server error?

Tags: mysql, internal-server-error

I have a function that checks if a row exists in MySQL.

It's returning an Internal Server Error to AJAX.

I'm running a similar function in another script that works fine.

I've tested that $mysqli is opening fine, and that the query itself works. It seems to be the

```
if (mysqli_result($result, 0) !== '0') return true;
```

line throwing the error, but this line works fine on the other script.

Anything obvious I'm missing here?

```
function exists($mysqli,$id)
{
    $query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `id`='". $id ."'";
    if (!$result=$mysqli->query($query)) send(3236,"e");
    if (mysqli_result($result, 0) !== '0') return true;
}

if(exists($mysqli,$id)) send("exists","e");
```

Here's another example where it's working fine:

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(`premium`) FROM `codes` WHERE `premium`='$code'";
if (!$result=$mysqli->query($query))
{           
    $errMsg="There was a problem checking your code - please contact support";
}
else
{
    if (mysqli_result($result, 0) !== '0')          
    {   
        echo 'premium'
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'non-premium'  
    }               

}
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Do you want this line `if (mysqli_result($result, 0) !== '0') return true;` to check the number of rows returned by the query? If so you would want to do `if ($result->num_rows > 0) return true;`

Comment: What does `send` do?